# How to assign the list of array to specific data?

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, select

I want to list out `affiliation` **without duplication** from my DB column `setting_name` from table `author_settings`. 
Here is my DB:

```
author_id | setting_name | setting_value
     1       affiliation   King College
     1       biography     Oncology Department
     2       affiliation   Queen Hospital
     2       biography     National Research Center
     3       affiliation   King College
```

Then, after the list, I want to set it according to the `author_id` from table `authors`:

```
author_id | author_name 
   1           Mary
   2           Hasan
   3           Dexter
```

First, I want all affiliation list out like this:

```
<affID> 1 </affID>
<affName> King College </affName>

<affID> 2 </affID>
<affName> Queen Hospital </affName>

<affID> 3 </affID>
<affName> National Research Center </affName>
```

then for the author, the affiliation will be assign according to author like this :

```
<authorID> 1 </authorID>
<name> Mary </name>
<affilitationID> 1 </affiliationID>

 <authorID> 2 </authorID>
    <name> Hasan </name>
    <affilitationID> 2 </affiliationID>

<authorID> 3 </authorID>
<name> Dexter </name>
<affiliationID> 1 </affiliationID>
```

and this is my code to list out the affiliation:

```
$affl=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT DISTINCT author_settings.setting_value, author_settings.setting_name,
                         authors.article_id
                         FROM author_settings
                         INNER JOIN authors ON authors.author_id=author_settings.author_id
                         HAVING author_settings.setting_name='affiliation'")
                         or die(mysql_error());

$affid=1;
while($affl2=mysqli_fetch_array($affl))
{
    $xml.='<affID>'.$affid.'</affID>';
    $xml.='<affName>'.affl2['setting_value'].'</affName>

    $affid++;
}
echo $xml;
```

I've try use `SELECT DISTINCT` to list the affiliation without duplication but for the second part, I don't know how to assign it to the author accordingly. Please help. Thanks :)

Comment: How exactly do you want to list affiliation without duplication if you combine this data with the display of authors, who may have the same affiliation? I do not understand what exactly you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

One way to resolve this is to create a temporary table that will contain the affiliation values and their indexes. To achieve this, the queries would be:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS affiliations;

CREATE temporary TABLE affiliations (
  aff_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  aff_name VARCHAR(45),
  PRIMARY KEY (aff_id) 
) ;

INSERT INTO affiliations (aff_name) SELECT DISTINCT setting_value FROM author_settings WHERE setting_name='affiliation';

-- Provide results for the list of affiliations
SELECT * FROM affiliations;

-- Provide results for the list of author, with affiliation index
SELECT auth_a.author_id, auth_a.author_name, aff_id
FROM authors AS auth_a JOIN author_settings AS auth_s ON auth_a.author_id = auth_s.author_id AND auth_s.setting_name = 'affiliation' 
JOIN affiliations AS aff ON auth_s.setting_value = aff.aff_name;
```